# RewriteRule htaccess with questionmark in url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to rewrite a url that contains the question mark to pass variables.

/?page=1 This url I want to Rewrite.

This doesn't work

```
RewriteRule ^\?page=10 http://webiste.com [R=301,L]
```

Anybody an Idea on how to do this, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use Query_string variable to match against querystrings in urls

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=10$
RewriteRule ^ http://webiste.com? [R=301,L]
```

Empty question mark at the end is important as it will discard the original query string from url.

Comment: `[NC,R=301,L]`, but no need to use `NC` because nothing to test, or you can add it with `page=`.